# Get the index of an array based on keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with an index. The index is not static and keeps changing.

```
$fields = [
  11 => array (
    'fieldId' => 'ORStreet',
    'type' => 'TEXT',
    'value' => 'Postbus 52',
  ),
];
```

Index of the above one is 11. But sometimes it becomes a different number.
One thing that always stays the same is the fieldId. How can i get the index of this array by only knowing the field id.

This above array is a child of the main array called 'fields'.

In my head i have something like this:

Loop through the main array called fields > if you find an array with fieliD => ORStreet. Return the index of that array.

If its not possible to get an index this way, i wouldnt mind if I got the 'value' => 'Postbus52' key-pair.

Comment: try `array_keys` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: _"Loop through the main array called fields > if you find an array with fieliD => ORStreet. Return the index of that array."_ What did you get when you tried that?

Comment: If you don't need the **11** for anything, then it's probably easiest to just use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to re-index the array by `fieldId` and access the element directly.

Comment: @AlexHowansky i havent done this yet, because i have no idea how to approach this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr = [
    [
      'fieldId' => 'ORStreet',
      'type' => 'TEXT',
      'value' => 'Postbus 52',
            ],
    [
      'fieldId' => 'vbnm',
      'type' => 'TEXT',
      'value' => 'Postbus 52',
            ],
    [
      'fieldId' => 'ORStreet',
      'type' => 'TEXT',
      'value' => 'Postbus 52',
    ]                               
    ];
    shuffle($arr);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(array_key_exists("fieldId", $value) && $value["fieldId"] === "ORStreet"){
            echo $key;
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

I have used `shuffle` method to simulate randomness of the array. Then I have loop through the array to match `fieldId` with specified value(ORStreet) . If it got match then the loop will terminates and display the index.

**Another Way:**

```
$filteredArr = array_pop(array_filter($arr, function ($a){
  return array_key_exists("fieldId", $a) && $a["fieldId"] === "ORStreet";
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

```
$index = array_flip(array_map(function($val){
    return $val["fieldId"];
}, $arr));
echo $index["ORStreet"];
// output: 11
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/1eLOG)

Answer (score 1):

One more possibility:

```
$result = array_keys(
    array_combine(array_keys($fields), array_column($fields, "fieldId")),
    "ORStreet"
);
```

`array_column()` extracts all the `fieldId` values, and then `array_keys()` searches for your desired value, returning the relevant array keys.

Note this will return an array of keys. If you only want the first key, this will return it as an integer:

```
$result = array_search(
    "ORStreet",
    array_combine(array_keys($fields), array_column($fields, "fieldId"))
);
```